# What is mean by the part '=+' of the below regex

Tags: regex

```
[A-Za-z0-9'"-.:\\*?@/\\\\!_#$%&()\[\]{}=+\p{Space}]+
```

I am confused about the part '=+' of the regex. Does it signify one or more occurance of the character '+' only or + is treated as a character that may be contained by the string?

Comment: `+` inside `[` and `]` is treated as literal `+` only.

Answer (score 3):

```
=+
```

is inside character class `[]` and so it has no special meaing and is treated as just literal characters.

[**Read more here**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)